# Callback function being called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I'm relatively new to Javascript and I am having an issue with retrieving JSON data that it is being called twice. Specifically, the getData function grabs JSON data and then retrieves the JSON object and execute the plotMarkers function (I'm working with Google Maps API). In checking the console, the callback function runs twice, which means the list items are appended twice. How can I fix this?

Specific code segment:

```
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.811748, 144.962886),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        getData();
    }

    function getData() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9546194/gigs.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(results) {
                plotMarkers(results.gigs);
            }
        });
    }
```

[Full code link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9546194/index1.html)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: where did u call intialize function()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of `onload="initialize()"` in `body`.

Both `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` and `<body onload="initialize()"` are calling `initialize`.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Been stuck on this for a while!!